# Postscript ghostscript output

Tags: printing, lifecycle, ghostscript, postscript

This might sound like a very foolish question but I've been reading around and haven't been able to understand the lifecycle of a print job.

<kbd>Program</kbd> → <kbd>PostScript</kbd> → <kbd>GhostScript</kbd> → ? → <kbd>Printer</kbd>

My doubt is, what ( if any ) comes in the place of **?** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your OS printer driver would fit in that spot. It receives the rendered output from ghostscript and converts it to a printer-specific format.

Comment: So, does the printer send data to the printer as a single page/line by line/ pixel by pixel or ???

Comment: Back in the 80s, one of the advantages of PostScript was its natural compression for mostly-text data. Nowadays, bus bandwidths are high enough that it's usually pixel data.

Comment: luser droog , I don't know if you have seen this question of mine , but could you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14544978/dynamically-change-print-data

Comment: specifics depend on the printer and os, and even then there may be multiple ways to configure things.  In some cases there isn't much of a system "driver" in the loop except for an interface to steer the data to the hardware.

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, in general Ghostscript isn't in that loop at all, though it depends very much on your printer and operating system.

In general you would send PostScript directly to the printer, which would have a PostScript interpreter built in. If you don't have a PostScript printer, then you would (normally) produce some other page description language (eg HP PCL) and send that to the printer.

However (expanding slightly on what george said above) on Unix systems you may be using CUPS (Common Unix Printing System), which does use Ghostscript to render PostScript to a raster format (CUPS raster) for non-PostScript printers. The CUPS printer drivers repackage the raster into a form suitable for the specific printer.

Note that modern versions of CUPS use PDF as an intermediate format and so Ghostscript may be involved twice, once to create a PDF from the PostScript, and once to render a PDF to raster (or indeed, to convert it back to PostScript.....)

Also, there is the gsprint application, which works on Windows, it uses Ghostscript to render a bitmap which is written to a printer canvas and then using GDI calls printed to the printer using the Windows printer driver.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go the ghostscript route, the question mark would be filled in with "gsprint" which is part of the "gsview" package.

gsview allows postscipt files to be viewed with ghostscipt, where gsprint allows postscript files to be sent to a printer with ghostscript.

http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/redmon/index.htm

Then to create a windows printer to be able to send the postscript output to, which would then run gsprint and output to a printer, you need "redmon".

http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/redmon/index.htm